# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, loading image in react

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to load an image from my static/images file, but I get the error

Avatar.jpg:1 Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently, no loaders are configured to process this file

webpkack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/frontend"),
        filename: "[name].js",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": {
                // This has effect on the react lib size
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
            },
        }),
    ],
};
```

Navbar.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppBar, Typography, Toolbar, Box, IconButton} from '@material-ui/core';
import {ArrowBack} from '@material-ui/icons'
import Avatar from "../.././static/images/Avatar.jpg"

class Navbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Box component="div">
                    <Avatar src={Avatar} alt=""/>
                </Box>
                <Box component="nav">
                    <AppBar position="static" style={{background: "#222"}}>
                        <Toolbar>
                            <IconButton>
                                <ArrowBack style={{color: "tomato"}}/>
                            </IconButton>
                            <Typography variant="h5" style={{color: "tan"}}>
                                Portfolio
                            </Typography>
                        </Toolbar>
                    </AppBar>
                </Box>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using webpack version prior to version 5. Webpack doesn't know how to parse the image files. Also you can notice that in your rules, you are asking webpack to use babel loader to parse javascript files but there isn't a module that handles .jpg files. In that case, consider using `file-loader` which is a module made just for that.
`npm i --save-dev file-loader`
then update your webpack bundle modules to this:

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "file-loader",
                },
            },
        ],
    },
```

For more options, you can check the docs for [file-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader)

Note that, webpack 5 deprecated the use of file-loader in favor of [Asset Modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/)

Answer (score 1):

Please add an appropriate loader for your file type. https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/

For png specific you can use:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

For example, for SVG icons we can have loader like:

```
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.svg$/, loader: 'svg-url-loader'}
        ]
    }
```

The problem is that icons are svg and you need a config for that in the webpack configuration.

Please refer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-url-loader

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I've tried omarwaleed solution first and it seemed to work.